# How to loop through an array and store its values in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following array :

```php
$catprefs = $request['catpref'];
```

Vardump :

```
array(5) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(2) "11" [2]=> string(1) "2" [3]=> string(1) "3" [4]=> string(1) "4" }
```

I need to loop this array and store each one of the values in a new row as follows :

```php
foreach ($catprefs as $save_catp) {
      $save_catp = new Cpref();
      $save_catp->user_id = $user_id;
      $save_catp->qatype = ????? ; // need to put the array value here
      $save_catp->type = 1;

      $save_catp->save();
}
```

How can I store each value of the array in the above insert ?

Comment: What's currently not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
foreach($catprefs as $save_catp){

      $cpref= new Cpref();
      $cpref->user_id = $user_id;
      $cpref->qatype = $save_catp; // need to put the array value here
      $cpref->type = 1;
      $cpref->save();

}
```

If you use `$key => $value`

```
foreach($catprefs as $key => $value){

      $cpref= new Cpref();
      $cpref->user_id = $user_id;
      $cpref->qatype = $value; // need to put the array value here
      $cpref->type = 1;
      $cpref->save();

}
```

Comment: I receive this error : Method App\Cpref::__toString() must return a string value

Comment: The field in the database is smallint

Comment: Edited answer please try now.

Comment: is it possible to create the object `new Cpref();` only once outside the loop?

Comment: Yes, @Yasin Patel given the answer below the answer. `Cpref::insert($data);` with array you can do it.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use bulk insert as below :

```
$data = [];
foreach($catprefs as $key => $val){
  $data[] =[
    'user_id' => $user_id,
    'qatype' => $val,
    'type' => 1
   ]
}

Cpref::insert($data);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(!empty($catprefs))
{
 foreach($catprefs as $key => $row)
 {
   $save_catp = new Cpref();
   $save_catp->user_id = $user_id;
   $save_catp->qatype = $row ; // need to put the array value here
   $save_catp->type = 1;
   $save_catp->save();
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($catprefs as $save_catp){
$save_catp = new Cpref();
```

you are using `$save_catp` in for loop and Cpref object, you need to change one of the variables.

```
if(!empty($catprefs)){
  foreach($catprefs as $key => $val){

  $save_catp = new Cpref();
  $save_catp->user_id = $user_id;
  $save_catp->qatype = $val; // array value goes here
  $save_catp->type = 1;


  $save_catp->save();

 } 
}
```